# How to stop cmake from trying to link against non-existing library?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cmake

I am sorry if this is a naive question, as I'm quite unfamiliar with CMake in general.

I am trying to compile a very large open-source software project (OpenCV). I seem to have get most libraries that is needed into the path using the following command line arguments.

```
-DCUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR='${CONDA_PREFIX}/include' \
-DCUDNN_LIBRARY='/${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib' \
-DC_INCLUDE_PATH=${CONDA_PREFIX}/include:/usr/local/include:/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu: \
-DINCLUDE_PATH=${CONDA_PREFIX}/include:/usr/local/include:/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu \
-DC_PATH=${CONDA_PREFIX}/include:/usr/local/include:/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu \
-DLD_LIBARY_PATH=${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
```

Indeed, CMake is able to find the libraries it needs, like CUDA, CuDNN, OpenBlas, FFMpeg, etc. Everything seems to go well for a while.

At the linking stage, however, CMake keeps attaching a weird library reference "-llib". lib is a non-existent library, of course. For example, one such command is

> cd /home/albert/app/src/opencv/build/modules/cudev && /usr/bin/cmake
> -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/opencv_cudev.dir/link.txt --verbose=1

> /usr/bin/c++ -fPIC    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type
> -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-undef -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-enum-compare -Wno-shadow -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed   -shared -Wl,-soname,libopencv_cudev.so.4.4 -o ../../lib/libopencv_cudev.so.4.4.0
> CMakeFiles/opencv_cudev.dir/src/stub.cpp.o   -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
> -L/home/albert/.conda/envs/denseflow  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/home/albert/.conda/envs/denseflow:::::::::::::::::::::::
> -ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt ../../3rdparty/lib/libippiw.a ../../3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv/lib/intel64/libippicv.a
> -lcudart_static -lpthread -ldl -lrt -lnppc -lnppial -lnppicc -lnppidei -lnppif -lnppig -lnppim -lnppist -lnppisu -lnppitc -lnpps -lcublas **-llib** -lcufft -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/home/albert/.conda/envs/denseflow -lcudart_static -lpthread -ldl -lrt -lnppc -lnppial -lnppicc -lnppidei -lnppif -lnppig -lnppim -lnppist -lnppisu -lnppitc -lnpps -lm -lpthread -lcublas **-llib** -lcufft

This causes the following error.

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llib
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make[2]: *** [modules/cudev/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudev.dir/build.make:89: lib/libopencv_cudev.so.4.4.0] Error 1

If I manually remove the "-llib" (both occurrences) from the C++ command, the command executes successfully.

What is happening here?

Although I'm unfamiliar with CMake, it feels like there should be a straightforward way to prevent CMake from doing this.

Thank you so much for your help.

**Update:** There does seem to be something wrong with the OpenCV CMake files. When I run CMake, one of its output is

> --     Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt cudart nppc nppial nppicc nppidei nppif nppig nppim nppist nppisu nppitc npps cublas **lib**
> cufft -L/usr/local/cuda-11.6/lib64
> -L/home/albert/.conda/envs/denseflow

The mysterious lib already appears here.

Someone on the Internet suggests modifying CMakeCache.txt manually, but I wasn't able to get it to work. CMake just overwrites it after my modifications.

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14909 is about Mac, but it suggests (a) upgrading your CMake to the latest version, and (b) adding `-DOPENCV_CUDA_FORCE_BUILTIN_CMAKE_MODULE=ON`. Maybe one of those helps you.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your command line arguments. It seems the error is coming from openCV cmake files themselves.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for the pointer. Unfortunately it did not help. I think Mohamed Kandeel is right. It's something with OpenCV, which I cannot fix easily. OpenCV is huge and I cannot afford to spend too much time on it.

Comment: But the OpenCV project undoubtedly has a mechanism for reporting bugs.  It would be at least community-minded to use it to file a report about this issue.  It is possible that doing so would even get you a solution in a relatively short time.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You are absolutely right. The problem is that I'm not using the latest version of OpenCV from GitHub. I did try that, but ran into some different problem, which I am also confused about. I will try to report something, but it's unclear if a half-baked issue would help much. There are a surprisingly large number of questions on cmake and opencv on stackoverflow, which indicates just how difficult it is to build OpenCV.

Comment: Fair enough.  Which prompts the question: do you actually *need* to build it?  There are pre-built packages available for many of the popular Linux distributions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's a good point. I can live without building it. Building with CUDA GPU support is supposed to accelerate things for about 5x-10x, but it's probably just easier to wait and work on other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the following CMake option.

```
-DCUDNN_LIBRARY='/${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib'
```

Removing this option solved the problem. It seems that this path should be to a file, not a directory. I'm not sure which file it should point to for CUDA 11.6 and CuDNN 8.3.2, but simply removing this line is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

it should point to cudnn lib file. on Mac use this

```
-DCUDNN_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda/lib/libcudnn.dylib
```